# Dice Game with a coin flip to keep playing.

Tags: probability, statistics

Here is the game: Suppose I have a *n* sided fair dice and a fair coin. Let *k* be the number of times I roll the dice before I have to flip the coin. Rolling a 1 on the dice "wins," the game is over if I flip the coin and it lands on tails. Landing on heads gives *k* more dice rolls, repeating until the coin lands on tails.

My question is, what should *k* be so on average I win exactly once before the game is over.

My intuition from thinking about some simple cases is leading me to believe k = .5/(1/n) but I don't have any convincing justification.

Comment: Win exactly once or at least once?

Comment: If you flip heads, do you then roll $k$ times before the next heads? Or do you flip after every roll for the rest of the game?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I made edits that hopefully addresses your questions. But exactly once, and yes landing heads grants *k* more dice rolls before you flip the coin again.

Comment: $0.5/(1/n)=n/2,$ so you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be the number of the first toss of tails.

Then $P(M=m)=\frac1{2^m}.$

The expected number of ones in $mk$ rolls is $\frac{mk}n.$

So the expected number of $1$ rolls is:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^m}\frac{mk}n=\frac kn\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac m{2^m}=\frac{2k}n$$

So you need $k=\frac n2$ to expect exactly one. If $n$ is odd, there is no exact $k,$ but $k=(n+1)/2$ is the smallest that will have expected value $>1.$